# IntelliJ Automatically create private fields / methods like in Visual Studio?

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellij-idea

In Visual Studio 2012 I can type something like `aString = ''`.  This variable hasn't been declared as yet and by pressing `ctrl + .` the IDE is wonderful enough to create a private datamenber named aString of type String.

Is there a feature that mirrors this in IntelliJ?

I found an option for auto inserting methods on https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_assistance.html but couldn't find anything relating to private fields.

I don't have access to the IDE at the moment before anyone suggests the obvious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by first typing only `""` and then `.var`.

This is called [Postfix Code Completion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/) and is very useful. There are lots of other completions other than the `.var` one. I often use the `.cast` postfix completion for example.

Use it like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you just start typing the name of your variable:

[image]

And finally there it is your complete line:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

If you write aString = "" and you click alt-enter you'll get an option to create a field (private by default) for it along with several other options.

[image]